# React : is it legit to keep state initial value in useRef?

Tags: reactjs

I came across a piece of code today:

```
useEffect(() => {
   // do some dispatch, etc
}, [dispatch, staticData, route]); // to follow eslint react's exhaustive-deps rule
```

In this case, the references of `dispatch`, `staticData` never change.

But the reference to `route` can change because we replace the query params in the URL on inputs change.

Solution 1: I can disable eslint react exhaustive-deps for this line. But I'm not confortable with it -> if someone edit this useEffect in the future, I want this person to be aware of this rule.

Solution 2:

```
const initialRoute = useRef(route); // I could also use const [initialRoute] = useState(route);
useEffect(() => {
   // now I have to use initialRoute.current to do stuff
}, [dispatch, staticData, initialRoute]);
```

It does the job and eslint is fine with it.

But I wonder: is there a better way to store an initial value than `useRef`?

Comment: Yes that approach is valid, one question, is also do you need the entire `route` object in the useEffect or do you maybe just need `route.location` or some specific properties ?

Comment: Hum, that's a really good question, but I'm actually using `route.params` in the `useEffect`.

Comment: Using `useRef()` in such a scenario looks like an overkill to me. Wouldn't memoization (`const initialRoute = useMemo(() => route, []`) do the job, instead?

Comment: ...if it doesn't bring you back to where you have started (empty array of dependencies), of course

Comment: Using `const initialRoute = useMemo(() => route, [])`, I just feel like I'm lying to React (not to mention `eslint react's exhaustive-deps`). But I see your point: in the end, I'm lying using `useRef`.